# Dual US/UK citizen but UK passport expired - problem on return to UK?

Tags: usa, uk, passports

I have dual US/UK citizenship. I'm soon visiting Switzerland using my US passport (as UK one needs renewing). Will this be a problem when I return to UK? If I carry my expired UK passport as well will this be enough to show immigration on my return? If not, what else should I bring to show them (birth certificate? bank statement? Letter from employer? National Insurance no.)? many thanks

Comment: I think this is a duplicaten question but I do not have the time to search. UK allows citizens to return with an expired passport. Your US passport will be accepted by the airline.

Comment: Thanks very much, Willeke. Likewise, I did not have time to search the site.

Comment: This is not quite a duplicate because in this question the valid passport was for a visa nationality, but the part about an expired passport being valid to enter the UK still applies https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51320/expired-british-passport-and-travel

Comment: Thank you. I think the difference is in our case (its actually my daughter flying) she was born in UK. I think in the question you cited, the woman with a UK passport was born in another country.

Comment: @SuzanneGreen I don't see why that makes a difference.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't. I'm just thinking that if immigration was concerned about whether my daughter is still a UK citizen (due to expired passport) it might help to show them her birth certificate as she was born in UK.

Comment: @SuzanneGreen A UK birth certificate alone doesn't prove you're British. An expired British passport is better proof of citizenship than a birth certificate could be.

Comment: @SuzanneGreen someone born in the UK after nineteen-eighty-something, both of whose parents weren't "settled" at the time of birth, is generally not a British citizen.  With only evidence of birth in the UK, your daughter would need additional evidence showing that you or her other parent had ILR, EU permanent residence, or a right of abode at the time of her birth.  With an expired UK passport, she doesn't need anything else.

Comment: Thanks, all.  I just don't want her having any trouble at the airport. She plans to get her UK passport renewed - but with all of the pandemic-related interruption to foreign travel, we didn't see it as a priority!

Comment: Side note for others: if you've renewed your UK passport recently, you would be required to send in other passports you own. These will be linked to your renewed passport, so Border Force can identify British passport holders from their foreign passports.

I regularly enter/exit the UK with my EU nation passport instead of my British passport because it is simply more convenient for me to use one passport for my entire journey.

Comment: A relevant link from a now deleted answer describing a US/UK dual citizen's trouble-free experience flying to the UK (where she resides) with a valid US passport and entering as a British citizen with her expired UK passport: https://britishexpats.com/forum/citizenship-passports-spouse-family-visas-uk-196/into-england-expired-passport-dual-citizen-817063/

Answer (score 7):

According to https://www.traveldoc.aero, an expired UK passport is sufficient by itself to fly from Switzerland to the UK if the passport has been expired for less than ten years.

You'll need to show the US passport to the Swiss border officers (or other Schengen officers, if that's the case) at the at the departure passport inspection, because you will have entered with that passport.

It's probably also a good idea to show the US passport to the airline to avoid complications.  If they ask about your duration of stay in the UK, you can show the British passport, but they probably won't ask.

There's no need to show the US passport to the UK immigration officer on arrival.  There's also no harm in showing it, so do whatever seems likely to result in the most efficient experience.

Comment: Thanks very much. OK, she will take both her US one and her expired UK one. I am so glad it sounds as if she will not have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have any issues. In fact, US passport holders can use the automatic eGates in the UK, so it is unlikely you'll have to speak to an officer at all, unless the gates are off or not working properly. Just place your US passport on the scanner, look at the camera, and wait for the gate to open. Do bring your expired UK passport anyway, though, to present with your US passport if you have to be processed manually.

Comment: The OP is planning to "return to UK" - presumable because they live there. It would not be a good idea to re-enter the UK using only their US passport, as they'd be entering as a visitor, not as a UK citizen/resident.

Comment: @brhans It's impossible for a UK citizen to enter the UK as a visitor. Regardless of what documentation they happen to be holding when they enter the UK. Any notional restrictions on leave attached to their US passport are simply void because (in this case) they cannot apply to the person who owns it.

Comment: @MJeffryes - certainly - but from the UK government's point of view, all they know is that a US citizen entered the UK as a visitor on such-and-such date and 6 months later overstayed their welcome. If the OP should subsequently ever have their US passport details made known to the UK for whatever reason they'll be inviting unnecessary bureaucratic trouble for themselves. It would be far safer and less future trouble to present an expired UK passport for re-entry to the UK.

Comment: @brhans this is all very vague. Please give a concrete situation where OP would encounter trouble if they successfully enter through the ePassport gates using a US passport.

Comment: I can’t understand what issue the UK citizen would encounter. Presumably if they return and do not travel abroad over the next six months, they’ll also have time to get a new UK passport for future travel. If they don’t have the time to get a UK passport, it means they’d leave before the leave to remain for 6 months expires. I certainly wouldn’t recommend waiting to get a new UK passport if they don’t have any imminent travel plans. But I really can’t see what trouble they’d have.

Comment: @MJeffryes How about if the OP ever needs some time in the future to enter the UK with a US passport again?

Comment: @NYCvisitor2228968 a British citizen who enters the UK with a foreign passport does not receive leave to remain for six months, notwithstanding any passport stamp or other document that claims to grant such leave.  Any such grant of leave is legally a nullity because no leave to remain is required nor even available to someone who has right of abode.  They don't need to get a British passport, and they don't need to leave.